# How to resolve Warning : The element 'entityFramework' has invalid child element 'providers'. List of possible elements expected: 'contexts'

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I'm playing around with EF different workflows. Yesterday I made a new project and `Entity Framework 6` was the first suggestion from `Nuget` so I decided to give it a try, also it is a very small project entirely for learning purposes so I guess it will be good experience to try `EF 6` since I've been working mostly with `Ef 5`.

My Application is based on `Code First` approach. The structure of the solution is shown in the print screen:

[image: Solution Tree]

The project `CodeFirstClasses` is meant to hold my Entites. For simplicity purposes and because I follow a tutorial I use only one class as you may see - `Customer.cs`. There I have :

```
public class RewardContext : DbContext
    { 
        //Specify the name of the base as Rewards
        public RewardContext() : base("Rewards")
        { 
        }

        //Create a database set for each data item
        public DbSet<Purchase> Purchases { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

    }
```

And the other classes - `Purchase` and `Customer` which are trivial, so I won't paste them here.

The other project as you can see is `Windows Forms` project with just one form and button on it. On the `click` event of the button I have all the logic for adding new records to my two entities hardcoded. Here is just a part of it:

```
    //some code...
    //Add the record and save it
    context.Customers.Add(newCustomer);
    context.Purchases.Add(newPurchase);
    context.SaveChanges();

    MessageBox.Show("Record Added!");
```

So far nothing different from what I'm used to with `EF 5`. I can build the project, I can run it, and everything is executed as expected. However I get this warning from the title :

`Warning    1 The element 'entityFramework' has invalid child element 'providers'. List of possible elements expected: 'contexts'.` And even though I'm using mostly `MS SQL Server Management Studio` I've noticed that I'm not able to manage my connections/databases from the IDE - `Visual Studio 2012`, but this was not an issue with `EF 5`.

My research narrowed down the possible source of problem/solution to manually changing the `App.config` file, but this is an area where I haven't got much experience especially when the IDE took care of it until `EF 6`. So I'll post both my `App.config` files for this solution :

The one from the `CodeFirstClasses` project :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

And from my `TestCodeFirst` project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

And the other possible solution that I found is : `updating the xsd for "validating" EF config section in web/app.config file to recognize newly added EF6 elements` which I'm also not aware of how exactly to do it.

Even though when I open the `MS SQL Server Management Studio` I see the database created for this application, the records are saved and generally it seems to work but yet I would like to resolve this warning and get to know how to set up my applications based on `EF 6` right.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can install the EF6 Designer for VS2012 from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40762) and it will update the schema that validates config files.

Comment: As asked by the OP - do you know if there's some xsd/xmlns I can add to always get the latest version of the schema for this section (without installing this big package)?

Comment: Actually it is possible. EF is open source so you can just get the necessary files from codeplex. Take https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EFTools/setup/EFToolsMsi/XmlSchemas/EntityFrameworkCatalog.xml and  https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EFTools/setup/EFToolsMsi/XmlSchemas/EntityFrameworkConfig_6_0_0.xsd and copy to `Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Xml\Schemas` folder (not it will probably want to override the catalog xml file which should be fine - just in case make a backup). You may need to restart Visual Studio.

Comment: @sinelaw - actually the EF6 package for VS2012 is much smaller than the original one VS2012 shipped with. AFAIR the original is ~72MB while the new one is ~25MBs. This was possible because we changed the way we handle loc stuff. So if you replace the original designer with the EF6 designer you actually may gain some space (and the config will be fixed)

Comment: Thanks! The .xsd file is also useful when not using VS to edit the config file. Having the sources is a treat in general, here's one more use case :)

Comment: Seems odd to me that this isn't part of the EF6 nuget package. I guess it can't manage those files?

Comment: This is part of EF Tooling for VS. EF Nuget package is only a runtime that is installed into your project and does not make any changes to VS installation.

Answer (score 6):

The configuration schema was changed from version 5 to 6. As it says,  the providers node was replaced with a contexts node.

The idea is that you can configure the providers individually instead of all contexts using the same provider.  (This goes in tandem with being able to have multiple contexts that reside within one database. This used to be called multi-tenant but was later renamed to be more concise)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but could you provide some working example using the `context` node, I've tried to find one but with no success. No customization, something general to replace my code with and have something to work with?

Comment: @Leron - here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556606.aspx is the description of the EF config structure.