# Instantiating ViewModel in XAML raises error: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I’m trying to write my first WPF project, using EF, and implementing MVVM.

(It's a project for CRUD of employees' requests to get permission to attend some particular course. The employees' ID, name, dept are fetched from a text file, to be displayed in a combobox. The project should save all relevant data (courses, employees who made a request, requests) in a DB)

When I instantiate a ViewModel from my View, as follows:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MainViewModel x:Key="myMainViewModel"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

…VS2012 reports this error (at the 2nd line of XAML above):

```
Error   String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

So, it seems VS2012 has a problem initialising my ViewModel.
The databindings, however, do work somehow. The project, as it stands, seems to run just fine. The Employees from the text file are properly listed in the combobox.

My ViewModel’s  constructor fetches data to be stored in a property’s field:

```
public MainViewModel()
{
    IList<Employee> employees = GetEmployees();
    _employeesCollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(employees);
}
```

The data are fetched from a text file (which works fine).

The error, however, is not shown after changing the constructor’s implementation as follows, and running the project again:

```
public MainViewModel()
{
    _employeesCollectionView = new CollectionView(new List<Employee>());
}
```

The Employee class has no properties (or fields) of the DateTime type.

I’ve tried removing the Employee class from my EF DbContext, but still get the DateTime error, so i suppose EF has nothing to do with that.

I’ve tried commenting out the sole control that has a binding to the ViewModel’s property Employees (in which the fetched employee data are stored).

So, now I've run out of ideas on how to fix this. Searching the web didn't help. Perhaps you can? I'd be most grateful if you do.

---

UPDATE:
Here's the code of the method that seems to be causing my trouble: GetEmployees, and the DataLoader object it uses:

```
   public IList<Employee> GetEmployees()
    {
        DataLoader dataLoader = new DataLoader();
        dataLoader.LoadEmployeesFromPayroll();
        return dataLoader.Employees;
    }

namespace Bijscholingen
{
    public class DataLoader
    {
        private const string _PATH_OF_DATAFILE_FROM_PAYROLL = @"C:\Test.txt";
        public List<Employee> Employees { get; private set; }

        public DataLoader()
        {
            this.Employees = new List<Employee>();
        }

        public void LoadEmployeesFromPayroll()
        {
            StreamReader streamReader = null;
            try
            {
                streamReader = new StreamReader(_PATH_OF_DATAFILE_FROM_PAYROLL, System.Text.Encoding.UTF7);
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("File not found");
                return;
            }

            this.Employees.Clear();
            //skip first line of text file (contains headers)
            streamReader.ReadLine();
            while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
            {
                //read textfile line byline
                string line = streamReader.ReadLine();
                string[] fields = line.Split(';');

                DateTime dateValue = DateTime.MinValue;
                if (DateTime.Parse(fields[6]) <= DateTime.Now &&
                    ((DateTime.TryParse(fields[7], out dateValue) && dateValue >= DateTime.Now) || fields[7].Equals(""))
                    )
                {
                    int idToFind = Int32.Parse(fields[0]);
                    Employee loadedEmployee = this.Employees.Find(e => e.EmployeeID.Equals(idToFind));
                    if (loadedEmployee != null)
                    {
                        loadedEmployee.EmployeeDeptsFromPayroll.Add(fields[5]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        List<string> deptsList = new List<string>();
                        deptsList.Add(fields[5]);
                        Employee employee = new Employee(Int32.Parse(fields[0]), fields[2], fields[4], fields[3], deptsList);

                        this.Employees.Add(employee);
                    }
                }
            }
            streamReader.Close();
            this.Employees = this.Employees.OrderBy(e => e.ToString()).ToList<Employee>();
        }
    }
}
```

The text file this method parses, has valid date values in it's last 2 fields. The last field is empty in some records (which is why i used TryParse for that field).

Comment: For further help in debugging, post the code for `GetEmployees`.

Comment: Where are you using `DateTime`, what is the format of the string, what is the current culture.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Akane.

DateTime is used in DataLoader (and in a class called Course, which has a property of that type).
As I don't know which string causes the error, I can't tell you what format it has. The dates in the text file are formatted just fine, and converting them seems to work just fine too.
Current culture is Belgium-Dutch (nl-BE).

Comment: I've added the code for `GetEmployees` to my original post above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `GetEmployees` must be throwing an exception on a convert from `string` to `DateTime`. I would look into that. When instantiating an object in Xaml (as you are doing by the call to `<local:MainViewModel x:Key="myMainViewModel" />`) any exceptions raised during construction will crash it. This is, as you can guess, because the UIControl you are instantiating that in turn tries to instantiate this object doesn't know whether or not the rest of the page depends on this object. There's no mechanism for a `try-catch` in Xaml.

Best practice is to avoid data-loading during construction so, at bare minimum, the page displays. Then, on the `Loaded` event for the control that instantiated this ViewModel, call an `Initialize` method on the ViewModel, which can then be `try-catch`'d and appropriately handled.

Comment: To test your hypothesis, I tried adding a button to my View, and putting `GetEmployees`' code in the code-behind. When i click that button while debugging, the data are loaded just fine, and i don't get any errors - except the one i'm trying to fix, of course.

Comment: Well that is as expected. You need to look into the error that is being fired. Look into the body of the GetEmployees method. Or post it so we can help.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and clarification!

The error, however, doesn't get fired while running GetEmployees in debug mode.
When I stop debugging, and open my View's XAML, the error is listed in the Error List.
Am I wrong in thinking that, if GetEmployees is indeed causing that error, it would also pop up while running GetEmployees in debug mode?

Comment: When i comment out all code that uses DateTime in the code triggered by GetEmployees, a different error is shown in the Error List: "_A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26"
Also, the xaml designer seems to hang until i kill it's process.

Comment: Oh, and thanks for your suggestion to avoid data-loading during construction. 
I've been trying to avoid using events and code behind, but the lack of try/catch sounds like a good reason to do that anyway.

Comment: You definitely want to leverage events and code behind, especially since you are using the Model-View-ViewModel pattern. But if you're getting that error on your SQL connection, you have an incorrect SQL connection string. Check your config file.

Comment: The DB connection **does** work, however, as the Courses are loaded from the DB and shown in my View.

I'm using EF with Code First to generate the DB. I don't remember having to set a connection string, or any config file. EF is set to `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges`, by the way.

When i open the App.config file, a warning appears in the Error List: _The element 'entityFramework' has invalid child element 'providers'. List of possible elements expected: 'contexts'._

Comment: In the meantime, I fixed the warning regarding EF mentioned in my comment above, by following the instructions in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19525902/how-to-resolve-warning-the-element-entityframework-has-invalid-child-element

Comment: I've found a work around:
removing the first condition below (which, luckily, i can do without):

`DateTime dateValue = DateTime.MinValue;
                if (DateTime.Parse(fields[6]) <= DateTime.Now &&
                    ((DateTime.TryParse(fields[7], out dateValue) && dateValue >= DateTime.Now) || fields[7].Equals(""))
                    )
                {
     ...
    }`

Comment: ...so that only this code remains:
    
`DateTime dateValue = DateTime.MinValue;
                if (                        
                    ((DateTime.TryParse(fields[7], out dateValue) && dateValue >= DateTime.Now) || fields[7].Equals(""))
                    )
                {
     ...
    }`

Comment: I still don't understand why:
* the error was listed in the Error List, but didn't pop up while debugging
* `DateTime.Parse(fields[6]) <= DateTime.Now` would cause an error at runtime, as all dates in that field are formatted according to current Culture.
The text file has no records in which that field is empty.
Excel has no problem with the text file's dates either.
Perhaps there's some glitch with the text file, or it's encoding (the rarely used UTF7)? But, importing it to Excel and saving as text file didn't help either.

Comment: I still get the other error (_error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified_), but i guess that is off topic in this post.